# how to write an arrow function within a class in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a function with properties but keep getting a syntex error.

I need to define my state but not sure where this should be placed.  What is the best way to write the below code?

```
UPDATED--
class TEST extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }
state = {isApp: false,}
 myFunction  = ({ isApp }) => {
    return (
    <div>
       <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  )}
}

export default TEST;
```

I am guessing that my arrow function should not be within the class?

The syntax error has gone but now the page does not load at all, I guess it doesn't know what to do with "myFunction "

Comment: Maybe post the error you're getting?

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected token (24:11)

  22 |     }
  23 |     state = {isApp: false,}
> 24 |     const myFunction  = ({ isApp }) => {
     |           ^
  25 |         return (
  26 |             <div>
  27 |                 {!isApp &&

Comment: Remove `const` in front of myFunction and you forgot the closing paren on the `return`.  You have one too many closing curly braces

Answer (score 1):

Initial state should be assigned to the instance in the constructor:

```js
class TEST extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {isApp: false};
 }

 myFunction  = ({ isApp }) => {
    return (
    <div>
       <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  )};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need an arrow function here. The body of that function could be placed inside the `render` function. As well, feel free to remove the `constructor`.

```
class TEST extends React.Component {
  state = {isApp: false,}
  render() {
    const {isApp} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          {!isApp  && <p>Hello World</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```